# In Redmine, how can I set one theme for desktop and another for mobile browsers?

Tags: redmine

I have found a theme I prefer for desktop browsers and a different one for mobile browsers. What's the best way to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

the only way to fully customize a theme and have it mobile friendly is by customizing the css stylesheet.