# In Google Chrome Browser, how can I set the theme for one system to be different from another system?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, themes

I have the following situation for my development using two hosts, a local and remote host.

- I'm working in an AWS Desktop (linux), this is the local system.
- I ssh into an EC2 instance to do my development (linux).  All (or most) of my files are on that system.  This is the remote host.
- Some systems work by saving files to your local system but I want to access my EC2 file system.   So I've launched Chrome from my EC2 instance.
- I have some Chrome windows that are launched locally (on AWS Desktop), and
- I have some Chrome windows that are launched remotely (on my EC2 instance).  I'm using ssh with support for X Windows to display the remote window locally.
- NOW, **which browser window is my remote window???  This is the problem I'm trying to solve.** It's easy when I just open it but after working and opening new windows and closing some, I'm not sure which is the remote browser because they all look the same.

I tried using Google Themes and make the remote theme different from my local theme but when I changed the remote theme ALL of my chrome windows changed to match that remote theme.  I'm sure it's because I have enabled Sync on google chrome (see https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) for details.

I also tried customizing my Google Sync settings and I disabled "theme" syncing, but this did not work, all browser windows were updated when I changed the theme.

So I'm trying to find out **how to make the remote window somehow look different from the local windows.  I need this so I know which browser to use to access the remote file system.**

**(Q) Is there a way to have everything synced except but customize the theme for one HOST?  Or is it an all hosts are synced or none are synced for themes?**

A search for an answer gave some questions about themes but not this question.

- This was the closest to what I'm asking.  [In Redmine, how can I set one theme for desktop and another for mobile browsers?](https://superuser.com/questions/725582/in-redmine-how-can-i-set-one-theme-for-desktop-and-another-for-mobile-browsers)
- Nope, not close.  [How can I get Google Chrome Application Mode to preseve the theme?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135342/how-can-i-get-google-chrome-application-mode-to-preseve-the-theme)
- Not related, [Unable to reset Google Chrome theme](https://superuser.com/questions/1442100/unable-to-reset-google-chrome-theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible.  If you have Chrome set to sync, it will sync your theme.  You can turn off syncing or use a different Google account which uses a different theme.

There may be 3rd party Chrome extensions that might do this, but I do not know of any.